# Python dictionary with list, how to describe it in a thrift stub code?

Tags: python, rpc, thrift

I am trying to send a python dictionary `{"1": ["2", 3, 4]}`. Server and client [as here](http://tkang.blogspot.com/2010/07/thrift-server-client-in-python.html), only used `TSocket.TServerSocket(unix_socket="socket")` and
`TSocket.TSocket(unix_socket="socket")`
accordingly.The function returns a dictionary called `get_stats()`.

**File `stats.thrift`**

```
struct Stat{
  1: required string login
  2: required i32 connections}
service Stats{
  map<string,list<Stat>> get_stats()}
```

**generation code** `thrift --gen py stats.thrift`

But when call the function, I get an error on the server side:

```
ERROR:root:'str' object has no attribute 'write'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  *more text*
  File "gen-py/stats/Stats.py", line 189, in write
    iter15.write(oprot)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'
```

**Function `write()`**

```
def write(self, oprot):
    if oprot.__class__ == TBinaryProtocol.TBinaryProtocolAccelerated and self.thrift_spec is not None and fastbinary is not None:
      oprot.trans.write(fastbinary.encode_binary(self, (self.__class__, self.thrift_spec)))
      return
    oprot.writeStructBegin('get_stats_result')
    if self.success is not None:
      oprot.writeFieldBegin('success', TType.MAP, 0)
      oprot.writeMapBegin(TType.STRING, TType.LIST, len(self.success))
      for kiter13,viter14 in self.success.items():
        oprot.writeString(kiter13)
        oprot.writeListBegin(TType.STRUCT, len(viter14))
        for iter15 in viter14:
          iter15.write(oprot)
        oprot.writeListEnd()
      oprot.writeMapEnd()
      oprot.writeFieldEnd()
    oprot.writeFieldStop()
    oprot.writeStructEnd()
```

why the thrift generated code:

```
for iter15 in viter14:
  iter15.write(oprot)
```

**Questions:**
Why called method `write()` for type `str`?
Where I'm wrong?
In `stats.thrift`?
In Server or Client code?
In `thrift --gen` command?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a problem in your handler's return code. You're probably putting a string value instead of the list. can you post your handler code?

Comment: `def get_stats(self):`
    `return {"1":["2", 3, 4]}`

Comment: @user1271033 well then, you should return something of the form ` map<string,list<Stat>>`. but you are not returning a list of Stats object - rather a mixed list of strings and ints. thrift can't serialize this.